# Possible to use iOS keyboard shortcuts to create HTML email signatures?

Tags: html, ios, keyboard-shortcuts, signatures

iOS allows HTML email signatures. But it's a blunt tool which can either be used all the time or not at all (on a per account basis).

Sometimes a spiffy email sig is appropriate. Other times (like when replying to an existing conversation) it's clearly not.

Would it be possible to use iOS's Keyboard Shortcuts to save complete HTML sigs as a phrase which could be invoked with a few keystrokes on an as-needed basis?

*How would you ensure the signature displayed as intended (and not as raw HTML code)?* Is there a way to get it to actually display an image instead of `<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg>`?

Answer (score 0):

Set up an "autocorrect" for a string of characters you would not normally use.

http://www.macworld.com/article/2031004/how-to-make-ios-autocorrect-work-for-you.html

This would also then work in text messaging. So you'd really want to use a string that you would not accidentally type.

EDIT:
You cannot type HTML into an email in IOS without a different app. (You cannot use the standard app.)

Here is a link to a tut.

http://www.imore.com/daily-tip-create-html-rich-email-iphone-markdown-mail

Comment: Yep, I understand that much. What I want to know is can I get it to display an image instead of `<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg>`? (I'll edit my original question to make this clearer.)

Comment: You cannot type HTML into an email in IOS without a different app. (You cannot use the standard app.)